# RSACryptoServiceProvider not available for Xamarin UWP

Tags: xamarin, uwp, windows-runtime

I am trying to Encrypt String using `RSACryptoServiceProvider` for Xamarin.Forms UWP App. But the API is not Available as it is working fine for Android and iOS.

Could you kindly suggest me how to fix this issue?

Thanks for the Help

Comment: The service provider should be available and should work in UWP. Please post some code so that we can see what is happening

Comment: just create RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(); in Xamarin forms shared code, run Xamarin Android or Xamarin ios , it Works but if i make Xamarin Uwp as startup project and run i am getting getting RSACryptoServiceProvider could not be found , are you missing library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right, it doesn't work directly in UWP. You should use [`RSA.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.create(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of `RSACryptoServiceProvider` in .NET Core.

For more details, check out this [thread on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10709) where a very similar problem is discussed.

You can also try installing a `System.Security.Cryptography` NuGet package in your UWP app. That way you may be able to use `RSACryptoServiceProvider` directly.

If all fails, you could implement this in a platform-specific manner on UWP, there is surely more info [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/cryptography).